# PayPal REST API v2/checkout/orders does not redirect back after approval

Tags: paypal

I've never used PayPal before, it's not really popular here, and I'm confused by how the order and payment works. Can anyone explain it to me? I've read the documentation and I'm still confused.

> To complete payer approval, use the approve link to redirect the
> payer. The API caller has 3 hours (default setting, this which can be
> changed by your account manager to 24/48/72 hours to accommodate your
> use case) from the time the order is created, to redirect your payer.
> Once redirected, the API caller has 3 hours for the payer to approve
> the order and either authorize or capture the order.

I have created a working PHP curl call for this API in sandbox env according to the sample
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create

The APIs I created before work like this:

1. Send a request to 3rd party payment
2. Get a response containing a checkout link
3. Redirect customer to link
4. Customer complete payment
5. 3rd party send a request containing order and payment detail to a file/path on my server
6. My server receives the request and updates the order status/payment in my database
7. 3rd party redirect the customer to my webpage

With PayPal, what I got so far is:

1. Send request containing order detail to /v2/checkout/orders
2. Get a response containing various links
3. Redirect my customer to the rel:approve checkout link
4. Log in to my sandbox customer account and pay using PayPal balance, click Continue
5. A popup message is shown: **We're sending you back to xxx's Test Store to complete this purchase**
6. The popup message is closed and I'm still at the same payment page with the Continue button as seen in the image

[image: PayPal payment page]

Comment: you have to pass a callback URL. It's very difficult to see what your issue is without seeing any code.

Comment: i have never worked with paypal before but i know that paypal have a sdk for php with many examples. maybe this will help you: https://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/

Comment: @Scriptable My request is the exact same as the provided sample on the link, only has intent and purchase_units. And I don't see any callback URL option in available request parameters.

Comment: @spinsch I have to download and install composer/library with the SDK. And I've tried it before I finally found the API I wanted, the SDK failed on me because I don't see any autoload.php in my downloaded files and it's required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Send request containing order detail to /v2/checkout/orders
> 2. Get a response containing links
> 3. Redirect my customer to approve link

Step (3) is an old integration method, for websites using an old redirect-based flow. The preferred way to integrate PayPal uses no redirects. At all. Your website remains loaded in the background. Do the following:

Follow the [Set up standard payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/) guide and make 2 routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). Both routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller.

Pair those 2 routes with the frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

---

If, for some odd and inexplicable reason, you insist on using the legacy flow with a full page redirect instead of what I just described above, you must include a `redirect_url` in your orders creation request, so that PayPal has somewhere to return to after the order is approved. Immediately when the return happens, capture the order with an API call and show the success/failure result to the customer. If you want an intervening order review step before capture, you can do this, but you must *also* edit your initial order creation request to change the verbiage of the last button at PayPal from "Pay Now" to "Continue" so that the user is clicking on something that corresponds to what the next step will be. `application_context.user_action` needs to be `continue` for this change.

Capturing an order will return a v2/payments object which is the completed transaction with its own ID for accounting and refund purposes.  (The order ID is only used during payer approval, and unimportant otherwise)

Comment: I ended up using the button and it works. I didn't use this at first because the client wants the API to be in pure PHP/server side, not JS library. But he has seen how it works and approves it.

Comment: The JS is only used instead of redirecting, all the API calls can still be server-side.

Comment: Thanks. It's a real pity the documentation is still obscure in 2022 about the goal of this param

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too, and I eventually got a solution from the documentation.

You have to add *application_context.return_url* to your request.

Attached is an example in PHP:

```
$postData = [
        "intent"              => "CAPTURE",
        "purchase_units"      => $purchase_units,
        
        "application_context" => [
            "return_url"    => "",
            "cancel_url"    => "",
        ],
    ];
```

You can make a whole lot of customisations to the PayPal Payment page by adding the Application Context option, For a full list of the possible customisations, you can check up the official documentation [Application Context Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/api/orders/v2/#definition-order_application_context)

Comment: I undertand only now that these params work only in server-side integration.

Answer (score 1):

Because **return_url** is missing.
Here is the below example with array that needs to post in JSON format

```
Array
(
  [intent] => CAPTURE
  [purchase_units] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [amount] => Array
                    (
                        [currency_code] => USD
                        [value] => 100
                    )

                [payment_instruction] => Array
                    (
                        [disbursement_mode] => INSTANT
                    )
            )
    )

[payment_source] => Array
    (
        [paypal] => Array
            (
                [experience_context] => Array
                    (
                        [return_url] => https://example.com/return
                        [cancel_url] => https://example.com/cancel
                    )

                [name] => Array
                    (
                        [given_name] => A
                        [surname] => B
                    )

            )

    )
)
```

Comment: The key here being that, unlike @Ayemileto answer, this one makes reference to `experience_context` which **as of 2023** is now the main Paypal way to do this. `application_context` has been deprecated.